# Why can't I download apps on my android phone?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have a Huawei ascend y300 4.1 android jelly bean .Every time I try downloading apps from google play it says "Couldn't install on USB storage or SD Card" I try deleting apps I don't use for memory space but it still doesn't work,How can I Sort this out ???

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to your phone's Settings > Storage

2) Unmount SD Card (your external SD card)

3) Download/install from the app(s) from the Store again

4) Go back to Settings > Storage - then Mount your SD card again (or reboot)

Or you can try this

1)Insert the sd card in you windows pc

2)You will find a folder named `android_secure` in it you will find the file named `smdl2tmp1.asec` delete it

(Make sure in pc folder options, the `show hidden files` are enabled and the `hide protected operating system files` is unchecked)

Source: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/?__utma=248941774.1239869885.1394634270.1397478323.1397568266.7&__utmb=248941774.1.10.1397568266&__utmc=248941774&__utmx=-&__utmz=248941774.1397568266.7.7.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=206227472)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's trying to install direct to your SD card.

1. Go to `settings`>`storage`>`unmount SD card`
2. Install the app
3. `mount SD card` again

Answer (score 0):

Better You Format and try again , still prob download your app from your Pc ,search playstore and download from it .If you havent set your mobile number ,set it .
Or
Download apks from http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/ in your pc and copy and move it to your Mobile phone